# Get count of all combinations of numbers PHP

Tags: php, statistics

My table has a column that contains 5 numbers comma separated. Example: `5, 12, 88, 155, 201,`.
There are total of `10000+ rows`. I need a way to calculate the count of each pair  in existing table.

**Rules:**

- No same number can exist in same record, all numbers are unique in 1 record
- Numbers are always ordered in ascending order and saved
- Max number is 255
- Min number is 1

I need to know for example how many times numbers `5 & 12` appear together or numbers `88 & 155` or numbers `5 & 155`.

One way I thought I could do is to have double for loops but seems to be slow and will not really work for triple combinations or four most common numbers.

**My code:**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 255; $i++) {
   for ($j = 1; $j <= 255; $j++) {
      // two numbers cant exist in same record
      if ($i === $j) continue;

      $total = $this->db->getTotalNumFrequencies($i, $j);
   }
}
```

**Example Records:**

Record 1: `5, 12, 88, 155, 201,`

Record 2: `1, 5, 55, 88, 255,`

Record 3: 1, `55, 99, 151, 191,`

**Example Output:**

Combination 1: `5, 88`, Count: `2`, Appears In Records: `1, 2`

Combination 1: `1, 55`, Count: `2`, Appears In Records: `2, 3`

now this code works fine to get 2 number combination counts. How would I get `3, 4 & 5` number combinations without using the nested loops? Is there a way?

Comment: My first thought is that, due to your demands, you've got to change the datamodel to a relational one.
Comma separated numbers in a string column will never perform closely as well as a separate table for the numbers, with a foreign key to the main record / table.

Comment: @twicejr I know but in this case the 5 numbers in a row is just 1 type. There might be cases where numbers in a row is 6 or 7. Cant have 5 columns in table because of that

Comment: I have posted an answer which is based on the datamodel I thought about.

Answer (score 0):

Example data model for use in your case, that will support SQL-based approach instead of looping:

```
CREATE TABLE `thingtable` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `thing_numbers` (
 `thing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `numberval` int(11) NOT NULL
)



INSERT INTO `thing_numbers` (`thing_id`, `numberval`) VALUES
(1, 5),
(1, 12),
(2, 5),
(2, 13);

SELECT COUNT(thing_id), thing_id FROM `thing_numbers` WHERE numberval IN (5,12) GROUP BY thing_id 
/*will show
 COUNT(thing_id)    thing_id    
 2                      1
 1                      2
 */
```